# Laravel testing file download always fails

Tags: laravel, download, phpunit

I want to write a test for file download, for this first I'm uploading the file, then calling the API to download the uploaded file, upload is succeeded, but download always fails, and shows `The file "/var/www/public/uploads/dWwECsHQpcwJuYTn6uaLmPxk4uINOeYOZYiZ86Oc.jpeg" does not exist`.
Following is my test function content:

```
Storage::fake('public');
$business = factory(Business::class)->create(['owner_id' => $this->businessUser->id]);
$response = $this->jsonAs($this->businessUser,'POST', '/api/file/business', [
    'file' => $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('invalid file.jpg'),
    'attachable_id' => $business->id,
    'attachable_type' => 'businesses'
]);

$response->assertJson(['name' => $file->hashName()]);
Storage::disk('public')->assertExists('uploads/' . $file->hashName());

$uploadRes = $response->decodeResponseJson();

$response = $this->jsonAs($this->businessUser, 'GET', '/api/file/'. $uploadRes['id'] . '/business/' .$business->id);
// This assertion always fails 
// If I dd above response, shows this message 'The file "/var/www/public/uploads/dWwECsHQpcwJuYTn6uaLmPxk4uINOeYOZYiZ86Oc.jpeg" does not exist'    
$this->assertTrue($response->headers->get('content-type') == $file->getClientMimeType());
$this->assertTrue($response->headers->get('content-disposition') == 'attachment; filename="' . $uploadRes['original_filename'] . '"');
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

And following is my download function content:

```
$attachment = Attachment::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
$path = public_path(). '/uploads/' . $attachment->name;

return response()->download($path, $attachment->original_filename, ['Content-Type' => $attachment->mime]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file exists in the **public/upload** directory as well as you can generate link for public directory files using `url()` function.

EX:

```
$attachment = Attachment::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
$path = url('uploads/' . $attachment->name);

return response()->download($path, $attachment->original_filename, ['Content-Type' => $attachment->mime]);
```

Comment: Has the same issue, the file exists because assertion after the upload is passed.

Answer (score 0):

In the download implementation , I noticed that `public_path` function is used.

[`public_path`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.2.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L632) function resolves from the service container probably creating a new path from the real path for `public` disk configuration.

[`Storage::fake`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.2.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Storage.php#L21) is setting disk path and returning `FilesystemAdapter` and you want to make sure that this is the instance used in the lifecycle for the test spec.

I suggest to try using [path](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.2.0/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L105) method from FilesystemAdapter via `Storage` facade to construct the path in the download implementation instead of the `public_path` helper function. For example:

```
Storage::disk('public')->path('uploads/'.$attachment->name);
```